# Is there a prime $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ such that there is some $x$ satisfying $x^{2} \equiv -1 \mod p$ and $x^{2} \equiv -1 \mod p^{2}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*My attempt to show existence*:

If $x^{2} \equiv -1 \mod p$ then write $x^{2} = kp-1$ for some $k$. So $x^{2} \equiv kp-1 \mod p^{2}$, and to satisfy $x^{2} \equiv -1 \mod p^{2}$ we must have $k = mp$ for some $m$. Then $x^{2} = mp^{2}-1$.

From here I am lost. I have also calculated multiples of smaller prime squares to see if I could find anything. I could always go the other way and assume that there is no $p, x$ that satisfy the claim. We then have $x^{2} \equiv -1 \mod p$ but $x^{2} \not\equiv -1 \mod p^{2}$. Perhaps start with $x^{2} \equiv -1 \equiv (kp-1)(kp+1) \equiv k^{2}p^{2}-1 \mod p$ ? I am probably missing something very silly as usual!

This is not homework - it came up when trying to solve an Olympiad problem. I was trying to show that $9999 \mod 10^{4}$ cannot be a square. In going by way of contradiction, I assumed that $a^{2} \equiv 9999 \mod 10^{4}$, whence $a^{2} \equiv -1 \mod 10^{4}$. This made me think of the above question.

Comment: If you mean that $9999+10^4n$ cannot be a square, the number is congruent to $-1$ modulo $4$, so cannot be a square.

Comment: "there is some $x$ satisfying: IF $x$ THEN ...  " --  what does that even mean? Of course, there will be plenty of $x$ that satisfy that implication: all the $x$ that don't have $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod p$ in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the title.

Comment: Still just looking at the title: If $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod p^2$ then AUTOMATICALLY $x^2 \equiv -1 \mod p$ as well. Do you just need an example? $p = 5$, $x = 7$.

Comment: The answer is yes. Example: $x = 7, p=5$.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks for being ever so kind.

Comment: If $p$ is of the form $4k+1$, then the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p^k}$ always has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IS IT true that

$$ (x + p)^2 \equiv x^2 \pmod {p^2} ?????   $$

In response to the edited question: suppose $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and we have found some $x_1$ such that $x_1^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p.$ Suppose we took $0 < x_1 < p.$ Next, as Andre indicated, there really is a related $x_2$ such that $x_2^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {p^2}.$ Take $x_2 = x_1 + t p,$ where $t$ is an integer, and we may take $0 \leq t < p.$ For that fixed value $x_1,$ there is exactly one such value of $t$ such that   $$(x_1 + t p)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {p^2}.$$

Comment: So this implies that $2xp \equiv 0 \mod p^{2}$, which implies that $2p \equiv 0 \mod p^{2}$. But this happens only when $p = 2$. So I guess it's only possible for $p=2$ ?

Comment: I don't get the point, sorry.

Comment: @quid this referred to an earlier version of the question. He asked, essentially, whether all square roots of $-1 \pmod p$ were square roots of $-1 \pmod {p^2}$ for some prime $p.$ This is not possible for $p \neq 2.$ The current version of the question is better.

Comment: I can see now what happened, thanks for the clarification.